# problems with .Net File Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, multiprocessing, file-mapping

There are two processes:

1. Win32, C++ -  writer
2. .Net 4.5, C# - reader

first process  creates a buffer and sharing for second process.

- (int)(buffer+0) - until when you can write.
- (int)(buffer+4) - until when you can read.
- ...             - block [size_mess][mess]

record circularity, ie when you reach the end of the buffer, seek to the beginning.

at some point occur error.

1 process waits for data to be read. 
2 process reads a block, but reading the old data (which were recorded during the previous pass).

tried used MemoryMappedViewAccessor, MemoryMappedViewStream... without effect

**possible of delay due to .NET?**

```cs
unsafe public void LoadFromMemory(string name)
{
    const UInt32 capacity = 1200;
    const UInt32 maxsize = 1024;
    MemoryMappedFile mf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(name,MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl);
    MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mf.CreateViewStream(0, capacity,MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    byte* bytePtr = null;
    stream.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref bytePtr);

    int size = 0;
    long pos_begin = 0x10;

    long pos_max = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref *((int*)(bytePtr + 4)), 0, 0);
    while (<work>)
    {
        while (pos_begin >= pos_max)
        {
            pos_max = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref *((int*)(bytePtr+4)), 0, 0);
        }
        size = (bytePtr[pos_begin + 1] << 8) + bytePtr[pos_begin];

        stream.Seek(pos_begin + 2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        work(reader);

//if here put a breakpoint, 
//in time of error  size ! = Watch.bytePtr[pos_begin] and all other data

        if (pos_begin + size > maxsize) pos_begin = 0x10; // to beginning
        else pos_begin += size;
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref *((int*)bytePtr), (int)pos_begin); // for first process
    }
}
```

Comment: "possible of delay due to .NET?" - A .NET probably isn't going to introduce some arbitrary delay that breaks your app... unless your app already has some race condition, which would probably get hit anyway. The real question is: Why all the `unsafe` code?

Comment: because of use byte*, I'm tried use MemoryMappedViewAccessor, MemoryMappedViewStream... without effect. race regulated Interlocked